# ExclusiveTouch per UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, multi-touch

I have a two UIViews filled with UIButtons. I want to only allow one button to accept touches at a time PER UIView. That is to say I want multitouch working if you have one finger in each group of buttons but not if you have both fingers in the same group.

Of course exclusiveTouch set on the buttons makes sure only one button at a time is touched but it does it for the entire window. Is there a way to only allow one touch per UIView instead of the entire window?

**Update:** So to give a better understand of the desired function. I want a user to be able to select a red and blue card using multitouch. Easy. BUT I don't want them to be able to select two red cards or anything like that. Problem is if I turn on exclusiveTouch on the cards only one card in the WHOLE WINDOW can be selected at a time. The desired functionality is to have exclusiveTouch only operate PER UIVIEW which each set of cards is wrapped in its own UIView already.

**Update 2:** Just wanted to throw in that I am trying to find a solution that DOESN'T involve subclassing or otherwise overriding UIView's touch controllers. That is a last resort.

[image: Here is an image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When touching down one of your buttons, you may set `userInteractionEnabled` property of another button to `NO` and set it back to `YES` while touching up.

**UPDATE 1**

Sorry, I was an idiot.

**UPDATE 2**

...

**UPDATE 3**

Finally I got back to XCode. This code works (if I understood your aim correctly):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *leftButtonsArray;
    NSMutableArray *rightButtonsArray;
}

@end
```

//

```
@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Objects Processing

- (void)buttonDownAct:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    NSArray *targetArray = nil;
    if ([leftButtonsArray indexOfObject:sender] == NSNotFound)
        targetArray = rightButtonsArray;
    else
        targetArray = leftButtonsArray;

    for (UIButton *button in targetArray)
        if (button != sender)
            button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
- (void)buttonUpAct:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSArray *targetArray = nil;
    if ([leftButtonsArray indexOfObject:sender] == NSNotFound) {
        targetArray = rightButtonsArray;
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else {
        targetArray = leftButtonsArray;
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    for (UIButton *button in targetArray)
        button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)loadView {
    leftButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    rightButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    float desiredWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 4, desiredHeight = self.view.frame.size.height / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectInset(CGRectMake(desiredWidth * (i % 2), desiredHeight * (i / 2), desiredWidth, desiredHeight), 10, 10);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDownAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUpAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

        [self.view addSubview:button];
        [leftButtonsArray addObject:button];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectInset(CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(desiredWidth * (i % 2), desiredHeight * (i / 2), desiredWidth, desiredHeight), self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 0), 10, 10);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDownAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUpAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

        [self.view addSubview:button];
        [rightButtonsArray addObject:button];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: couldn't I still touch down simultaneously and grab too buttons? I already disable buttons on touchup but if I let up at the same time it still allows the selector to fire on both.

Comment: Well, I didn't really understand, what exactly you want. Can you post some code and (desirable) screenshot?

Comment: I just verified. Disabled all the buttons on touchdown doesn't prevent simultaneous touches. So if I touch one, then another yes this works. but if I time both my touches to be exactly the same I still select both buttons. I'll update my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Yea I'm afraid that doesn't work. I tried something similar and I just tried your exact code. The simultaneous touches still stump it. If you touch down exactly the same time and touchup exactly the same time you still end up firing the touchDown and TouchUp methods twice.

Comment: Well thats almost working. Couple things. One if you drag off a button then touchUp doesn't get called. Which means the buttons are now disabled for good. Second now if you simultaneously hit no button gets selected I'm guessing because both buttons get disabled by the other lol. Both those problems lead to VERY unnatural feels for touching.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt try this, but anyway.
Can you make two UIView on the main view, one for red buttons and one for blue ones. And set exclusive touch for your buttons?

Comment: Thats what I was doing to start. Exclusive touch always refers the window not a parent view.